# How to define angular js filter in Custom widget in Bonita

Tags: angularjs, bonita

I created a simple custom widget with Angular Js in BONITA UI designer.
I define the app controller inside the controller
I am not sure about the part and how it works in BONITA
I added all asset as well.

```
   app.filter('startFrom', function() {
   return function(input, start) {
   start = +start;
   return input.slice(start);}})
```

to

```
var startFrom= $filter('filter');
startFrom([],  function(input, start) {
if (input) {
start = +start;
return input.slice(start);}
return [];});
```

However, it seems not working properly.

I would like to know if I miss some part.
Any help appreciated .

Thanks in advance.
The template code is

```
 <input ng-model="q" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter text">
 <ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:q |startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | 
limitTo:pageSize">    
    <div>{{item.firstname}}</div>
   </li></ul>
  <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">Previous </button>  {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}  <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getData().length/pageSize - 1" ng- 
     click="currentPage=currentPage+1">  Next </button>`
```

the controller is

```
   function sds($scope, $filter) {
    var ctrl = this;

    $scope.startFrom=0;
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data =  [
  {
   "firstname": "Studio", 
   "userName": "studio"  
   },
  {
   "firstname": "Giovanna", 
   "userName": "giovanna.almeida"  
  },
  {
   "firstname": "Daniela",
   "userName": "daniela.angelo"
  },
  {
   "firstname": "Walter",
    "userName": "walter.bates"
  },
 {
   "firstname": "Giovanna", 
   "userName": "giovanna.almeida"  
  },
  {
   "firstname": "Daniela",
   "userName": "daniela.angelo"
 },
 {
   "firstname": "user1",
    "userName": "user1.name"
 },
 {
  "firstname": "user2",
  "userName": "user1.name"
 },
 {
  "firstname": "user3",
   "userName": "user1.name"
 },
 {
   "firstname": "user4",
    "userName": "user1.name"
 }

 ];

    $scope.q = '';

    $scope.getData = function () {
  return $filter('filter')($scope.data, $scope.q)
}

$scope.numberOfPages=function(){
    return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length/$scope.pageSize);
}

for (var i=0; i<65; i++) {
   // $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
}

$scope.$watch('q', function(newValue,oldValue){                      
    if(oldValue!=newValue){
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
  }
}

  var startFrom= $filter('filter');

  startFrom([],  function(input, start) {
        if (input) {
    start = +start;
   return input.slice(start);
   }
   return [];
   }
 ); 


 /*
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
start = +start;
return input.slice(start);
}})
*/

}
```

Comment: so, could you explain exacly what your filter is supposed to do?

Comment: when I search the text, the result is only from the current page,  I would like to show the result fo search from the whole table, not the current page. So, I found an example what I want to do, however, it is not easy to customize in BONITA custom widget. Thanks.